# Conditional object population

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hy guys, I've turning around a problem using Struts2.
Basically I've a form that the user can submit filling different fields. I would like to populate conditionally the right object with the properties insert by the user.

So for example, if the user fill the form in a intermediary way I would like to use the properties for to create an `Intermediary` object, instead if the user fill the request in entity way, i'll use the properties for to create the `Entity` object, ecc...
These object share the same interface `Request`.

Is there any way to use polimorphically properties for to create  `Intermediary` or `Entity` object?

Suppose this is my two POJO:

```
public class Intermediary implements Request{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String code;
    private String FiscalCode;
    private String address;

    ...
    /*Getters and setters */
    ....
}

public class Entity implements Request{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String code;
    ....
    /*Getters and setters */
    ....
}
```

This could be my form into the jsp page:

```
<s:form action="fillRequest" id="formRichiesta" name="formRichiesta" method="post">
    <s:radio id="tipoRichiedente" name="tipoRichiedente" list="richiedenti">
    <label>Name</label><s:textfield name="name"/>
    <label>Surname</label><s:textfield name="surname"/>
    <label>code</label><s:textfield name="code"/>
    <label>Adress</label><s:textfield name="adress"/>
    <label>Fiscal Code</label><s:textfield name="fiscalCode"/>
</s:form>
<s:submit>
```

Basically my problem is that I can discover the kind of request the the user trying to fill only ofter submission and watching at the radiobutton state.

Is there any way to mapping the properties into the right object directly instead of creating one big object with all the form properties and then create the right implementation? for to map properties could I use the interface reference?

For example image my action:

```
public class RequestAction {
   private Request request;
   ....
}
```

So in my jsp could I use:

```
 <label>Name</label><s:textfield name="request.name"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can map entity properties directly to the form fields, what is the necessity to write intermediate objects and transform them to the entities?

Comment: Because I can't know what object is it until i submit the form.

Comment: You can't know because you didn't use any object. The action instance will be used to populate your form data.